# Resetting Entity field with a collection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have realized a small Spring Roo project and have following problem. I have a Spring Entity with a field defined as set:

```
public class DataClass {
  ...
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "dataClass")
  private Set<SubDataClass> fields = new HashSet<SubDataClass>();
  ...
}
```

As it can be seen, it references a sub class which is mainly the following:

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "name","dataClass" }))
public class SubDataClass {
  @NotNull
  private String name;
  @NotNull
  @ManyToOne
  private DataClass dataClass;
}
```

If I want to store a dataClass object with several subDataClass values, it works great. Now, I want to update the dataClass object and replace all subDataClasses. I do this by resetting the set:

```
dataClass.getSubDataClass().clear();
SubDataClass newTest = new SubDataClass("sameNameAsBefore");
dataClass.getSubDataCleass().add(newTest);
```

If I merge this object now, I get a constraint violation exception as the object newTest uses the same name as an already stored object.

So the question is: how can I reset the field so that Spring / Hibernate is deleting the values within the set first before it inserts the new ones?

Thank you for your Help
Mathias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that flushing the entityManager between the two operations (clearing the set and adding new elements) will do the trick but I would have expected JPA to trigger the persistence update in the right order.

Is the dataClass entity still attached to the persistence context when you update its state ?